# (Tradingview lightweight) Crooked line graph when switch data arrays

Tags: javascript, html, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I'am trying to display 2 different graphs on the same canvas upon click of an onclick function.

My page defaults to the 1 Min line graph and a volume(histogram) graph at the bottom. The lightweight charts can draw the line and volume graphs without any issue.

When I switch my graph to a 3 Min graph, the volume graph gets displayed without any issue but my line graph gets crooked. As shown in the attached image.

Before I draw the 3 Min graph I would remove both the 1 Min line and volume serieses, after that I would create the 3 Min line and volume serieses and add in the 3 Min line and volume data arrays.

How can I solve this issue?

[image: Crooked Line graph]

Comment: Please provide a link to jsfiddle. Right now it looks like you provide unordered by time data items.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Seems like it might be caused by duplicate timestamps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original code, I had four serieses:

- 1 min candles
- 1 min volume
- 3 min line
- 3 min volume

I modified my code to have only 3 serieses:

- candle
- volume
- line

And change the datasets accordingly using the `series.setData` method.

The graph now shows the data properly.